# Code my android flash camera like native camera

Tags: android, flash, camera, native, light

I developed a camera in my app but when a set flash mode on and take a picture the light that comes out is to short and doesn't works on final picture. How can I develop my flash light like native camera that shows 2 or 3 levels of flashlight when takes a picture?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. When I click the takepicture button first I turn on the flashlight with param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH); for 1 second, after I set param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON); and call takepicture method. This way I can simulate native camera flash

Comment: nice work.please help me if you know how to set camera preview full screen like camera preview provided by vendor camera app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your flash light to work as torch.

First, apply permission in AndroidManifest.xml as follows,

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

Now use the below code to start the flash light

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();     
Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(param);
camera.startPreview();
```

and the below code is for off the flash light

```
camera.stopPreview();
camera.release();
```

Comment: he problem is when I set flashmode as Torch, the light turns on and never turns off. At this pointparam.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH); I just want like native camera when you take a picture with the flashmode on and its shows the light 2 or 3 times

Comment: did you try the last two line to turn off the flash light ?

Comment: So when you want that I write this code? 
    Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
    param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    mCamera.setParameters(param);
    mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallBack, myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);

Comment: Using the flash like youre telling me, it'll works like FLASH_MODE_ON, The light will appears only once and very fast